# PHP ssh2_exec se ejecuta el comando especificado pero al parecer no se liberan los recursos de la conexion al instante

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, symfony-messenger

Empleo la extensión *php-ssh2* para ejecutar un comando sobre determinados directorios del sistema operativo remoto; específicamente el comando `setfacl`. La tarea la ejecuto en un worker separado y una vez finalizado el proceso se notifica a la UI mediante un mensaje despachado en el hub de mercure. Se aplica un bloqueo mediante el componente Lock de Symfony (almacenando la clave en redis) para evitar el usuario lance más de una tarea simultánemamente.
La cuestión es que se está quedando bloqueada la ejecución del worker porque al parecer los stream resultantes del comando ssh2_exec() se quedan abiertos a pesar de que sí se ejecuta el comando (en este caso se aplica la acl sobre el directorio especificado), esa es mi teoría.

Esta es la clase que ejecuta el comando vía ssh:

```
class SSHService {

    private $sshConnection;

    public function __construct(private readonly string $sshUser, private readonly string $sshPassword, private readonly string $sshHost="127.0.0.1", private readonly int $sshPort=22) {
        
    }
    
    public static function create(string $sshUser, string $sshPassword, string $sshHost="127.0.0.1", int $sshPort=22):self{     
        return new static ($sshUser, $sshPassword, $sshHost, $sshPort);
    }
    
    private function _connect(){
        $this->sshConnection = ssh2_connect($this->sshHost, $this->sshPort);        
        if(false !== $this->sshConnection){
            // por ahora no comprobar firma.
            $fingerprint = ssh2_fingerprint($this->sshConnection, SSH2_FINGERPRINT_MD5 | SSH2_FINGERPRINT_HEX);
            if(!ssh2_auth_password($this->sshConnection, $this->sshUser, $this->sshPassword)){
                throw new \Exception("Fallo la autenticacion con el servidor SSH");
            }
        }else{
            throw new \Exception("No se pudo conectar al servidor SSH");
        }
        
        return $this->sshConnection;
    }
    
    private function _disconnect():bool{
        return ssh2_disconnect($this->sshConnection);
    }
    
    public function executeCommand(string $command):string{
        try{
            $this->_connect();
            $stdout_stream = ssh2_exec($this->sshConnection, $command);
            
            $output_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDDIO);
            $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($$stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
            
            stream_set_blocking($output_stream, true);
            stream_set_timeout($output_stream, 15);         
            stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
            stream_set_timeout($errorStream, 15);                       
            
            $errOutput = stream_get_contents($errorStream);
            if(!empty($errOutput)){
                throw new \Exception($errOutput);
            }
            
            $output = stream_get_contents($output_stream);
        }catch(\Exception $exc){
            throw $exc;
        }finally{
            $this->_disconnect();
        }
        
        return $output;
    }
    
}
```

En el `invoke` de la clase MessageHandler le llamo:

```
$result=SSHService::create($sshUser, $sshPassword)->executeCommand("/usr/bin/setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx ".$specificDir);
```

**Nota**: El rollo de ejecutar la tarea en un worker separado está dado porque me llamaba la atención tanto tiempo en una conexión al propio servidor web mediante ssh y ejecutar un simple setfacl. Por cierto, El timeout de 15 segundos establecidos en la funcion executeCommand no libera los recursos.

Comment: Revisa [este comentario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ssh2-exec.php#87745) en la documentación, donde plantea el problema de bloqueo en programas silenciosos -como `setfacl`-, necesitas alguna señalización. Por otro lado, toma en cuenta lo truculento del manejo simultáneo de stderr y stdout, también comentado en la documentación.

Comment: @Sal gracias por el comentario. Efectivamente no me ha servido con ssh2_exec por el mismo motivo que el comentario que citas de la documentación, he cambiado para phpseclib y funciona de sin problemas. Publicaré la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente y como cita el usuario @Sal un [comentario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ssh2-exec.php#87745) de la documentacion oficial de `ssh2_exc` es el caso que estoy enfrentando. Básicamente se estaría ejecutando de manera "asíncrona" un comando que explícitamente no escribe en la salida estandar (stdout).

Para no enredarme más hice uso de phpseclib y su clase `SSH2`.
Dentro de las ventajas además de algunas comparativas de rendimiento que encontré a su favor, pues ya implementa con la llamada a la función exec(), las salidas `stdout` y `stderr`; la posibilidad de enviar al servidor una serie de comandos separados por ; y en el caso en específico de la ejecución de setfacl (silencioso) me funciona perfectamente.
Quedando la clase SSHService:

```
namespace App\Infraestructure;

use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;

class SSHService {

    private $sshConnection;

    private function __construct(private readonly string $sshUser, private readonly string $sshPassword, private readonly string $sshHost="127.0.0.1", private readonly int $sshPort=22) {
        
    }
    
    public static function create(string $sshUser, string $sshPassword, string $sshHost="127.0.0.1", int $sshPort=22):self{     
        return new static ($sshUser, $sshPassword, $sshHost, $sshPort);
    }
    
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function _connect(){
        $this->sshConnection = new SSH2($this->sshHost, $this->sshPort);
        if (!$this->sshConnection->login($this->sshUser, $this->sshPassword)) {
            throw new \Exception("Falló la autenticacion con el servidor SSH");
        }

        return $this->sshConnection;
    }
    
    public function executeCommand(string $command):void{
        try{
            $this->_connect();
            $this->sshConnection->exec($command);
            $this->sshConnection->enableQuietMode();
            $error=$this->sshConnection->getStdError();
            
            if(!empty($error)){
                throw new \Exception($error);
            }
        }catch(\Exception $exc){            
            throw $exc;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Notar que `executeCommand()` es void, ya que no necesito salida en caso de éxito, solo error mediante una Exception en caso de falla de la ejecución del comando.